# How to extract substring between two characters Python

Tags: python

I'm a Python newbie and I need to extract a substring between two characters how can I do?

Example:

Mail field:

mail:"marco.xx@hotmail.it"

I need to extract the substring: marco.xx@hotmail.it

Many thanks for your help,
Marco

Answer (score 0):

You can use *split()*

```
text = 'Mail mail:"marco.xx@hotmail.it"'
email = text.split('"')[1]
```